# jupyter notebook can't see GPU while it is available in conda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to use tensorflow on GPU with jupyter notebook. I make SSH connection to a remote server with VScode and build up an anaconda environment(called 'myspace') where tensorflow(version 2.6.0) is successfully installed:

```
(myspace) user@server:~$ python
Python 3.6.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun  4 2021, 14:25:59) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print("Num GPUs:", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
Num GPUs: 1
```

However, when I open a jupyter notebook and select the same conda environment as its kernel, the GPU can't be seen:

```
Num GPUs: 0
```

I suppose that the CUDA toolkit and CUDNN library are successfully installed and I attach the output of *tf.sysconfig.get_build_info()* here:

```
OrderedDict([('cpu_compiler', '/usr/bin/gcc-5'),
             ('cuda_compute_capabilities',
              ['sm_35', 'sm_50', 'sm_60', 'sm_70', 'sm_75', 'compute_80']),
             ('cuda_version', '11.2'),
             ('cudnn_version', '8'),
             ('is_cuda_build', True),
             ('is_rocm_build', False),
             ('is_tensorrt_build', True)])
```

I've read many related posts but none of them worked. I tried to get the os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] and got a keyerror. I suppose it might be a problem of system path but I already set the paths in ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH=/home/user/cuda-11.2/bin:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/cuda-11.2/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Comment: Can you test it with pytorch?

Comment: I've tried with pytorch and it works successfully in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please verify if you have followed all the Hardware/Software requirements and instruction steps mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux_1) to enable GPU support with tensorflow in your system. Also please ensure that you are installing compatible CUDA and cuDNN with the specified tensorflow version as per this tested [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).  Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: This is the exact problem i am having but i can't find a way to solve it. I also don't want to use pytourch. Is there no solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could solve this problem was to change to tensorflow's image as jupyter image did. From here you could update from the comand line.

`docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --name jupyter --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/tf  --gpus all -e CHOWN_EXTRA="/home/jovyan/work" --user root -e GRANT_SUDO=yes -e NB_GID=100 -e NB_USER:jovyan tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`